# Can we replace cron job with apache kafka

Tags: php, apache-kafka, cron

I want to replace my cron job with apache kafka using php.

Is this possible?

Now my cron does work as updation on databases. Also sending email, sms depend on conditions. Also periodically updation in databases.
And daily backup of database.

Is it possible to implement this using kafka

Comment: Don't you think, you will need one cron job to trigger `kafka`?

Comment: ya i know that cron job is needed. but is there another method to trigger kafka

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your entire environment in terms of events rather than "batch time slots", but yes, it's possible in theory. As a shim, you can start with a Kafka process in Cron that will read messages for a configurable amount of time (or max amount of messages), and then process that chunk.

As for what you have asked for, you can make a CDC / changelog topic for database events (if you make this a compacted topic, you remove the need for a daily backup, as every database event is persistent in Kafka from the beginning of your DB history - look at the Debezium project for a starting point), and you can derive corresponding `emails` or `sms` topics which you have consumers polling and firing off SMTP, SMS, or GCM/APNs messages as you're probably already doing if this is the system you are migrating from.

None of this necessarily needs to be in PHP either (or really Kafka over another pub-sub system, for that matter). I would implore you to consider a microservices based approach that uses a client library and technology that makes most sense for your use cases. For example, AWS can integrate Kinesis (or MSK)+SNS+SES and you have an equivalent Kafka+SMS+Email solution with no infrastructure to maintain yourself.

Before you can go down this path, though, you need to stop batching your data into slices for Cron to process, and rather publish the data event-by-event, and do continuous, rolling aggregations as necessary over some time windows